# context.fillText() output being overwritten on updating the content to be displayed

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am creating a snakes game using canvas on html and javascript. My Game loop contains 2 methods-update and draw. In the draw method I am trying to display the current score at (50,50). When the score gets updated and the value printed on the canvas, the updated score is being written on top of the score from the previous iteration of the game loop. How do i correct this error. Pls note the score updation and the general functioning of the game is working, its only the displaying part of the score which is an issue.    i am using contextObj.fillText(score,50,50) to display the result in the draw method.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use `clearRect` at the top of your game loop to clear the area each time before drawing the next frame: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

```js
contextObj.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```